# Add a Binary File for Xcode to use

Tags: c++, xcode, binary

I'm sure that this is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a bin (binary) file that my C++ command line program needs to use. My program reads this premade bin file and using the information, sorts some stuff, but it does not ever write to the bin file. When I tried to drag the bin file into Xcode it appears red. It also does not appear to be able to be read. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Are you running your program in Xcode and it can't find the binary file?

Comment: @aichao yes that would be correct

Comment: @aichao any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Adding the binary file to the Xcode project/workspace is actually immaterial. The issue is setting the working directory for running the executable in Xcode to the directory where the binary file is located. This assumes that within the program code, the file is opened in the local working directory (i.e., there is no full nor relative path specified for the file). To set the working directory in Xcode:

1. Edit the scheme for the target.
2. Go to the Options tab under Run in the scheme editor.
3. Click on the Use custom working directory checkbox.
4. Select or enter the working directory (absolute path).

If you need screen shots, let me know.

Hope this helps.